# How to disable button looking "pressed" when Gallery slide is pressed?

Tags: android, gallery

I have a gallery. Each slide has a button inside.

I have a custom layout which with I'm inflating the slides.

Attached a click listener to the button and it works well, gallery also scrolls normally.

But when I press on the gallery outside of the button, the button is also pressed and turns blue. This doesn't trigger the onClickListener of the button. But it makes the button look like it was pressed and I don't want that.

Tried setting all listeners of the gallery to empty implementations but no effect...

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Attached an empty click listener to the custom layout and now the button doesn't become blue anymore but the gallery doesn't scroll because the event is consumed. Will see what can be done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for this. It's horrible, but it works.

First of all, the part of Gallery's code responsible for my problem is this:

```
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

    // Kill any existing fling/scroll
    mFlingRunnable.stop(false);

    // Get the item's view that was touched
    mDownTouchPosition = pointToPosition((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());

    if (mDownTouchPosition >= 0) {
        mDownTouchView = getChildAt(mDownTouchPosition - mFirstPosition);
        mDownTouchView.setPressed(true);
    }

    // Reset the multiple-scroll tracking state
    mIsFirstScroll = true;

    // Must return true to get matching events for this down event.
    return true;
}
```

More exactly this line:

```
mDownTouchView.setPressed(true);
```

Here the layout of my slide is pressed and the default behaviour of setPressed of LinearLayout is dispatching it to all childrens so all children are pressed.

First I tried making a subclass of Gallery and override onDown. If I just returned false and nothing else, it worked but the slides got strange behaviour of jumping to the next slide when touched. That was because of this line:

```
 mFlingRunnable.stop(false);
```

Which was not executed. Since this variable is private and related to everything else in Gallery class I didn't find a way to use it from the subclass. I tried also copying all the Gallery code, but it also didn't work, because it uses lot of things which only have package access... etc.

So I created a subclass of LinearLayout, which overrides onSetPressed:

```
public class LinearLayoutOnSetPressedDoNothing extends LinearLayout {

public LinearLayoutOnSetPressedDoNothing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
}
}
```

And use that in my layout instead of the LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.test.LinearLayoutOnPressDoNothing
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

    <!-- content -->
</com.test.LinearLayoutOnPressDoNothing>
```

And well, this works.